# How to declare large 2D char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to declare a large 2D (50,000x 50,000) char array in C. Can we do that ? And if yes how ?

Comment: Read about `dynamic memory allocation`.

Comment: [check this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/)

Comment: You can 1. Use dynamic memory allocation or 2. declare the array as a global. It is unlikely that such a large memory can work on the stack.

Comment: If 46340 is big enough try `char a[46340][46340];` outside of main()

Comment: The only thing special about this example is the size (a shade above 2GB). It's the question about allocating a 2D array or something to do with the size? If the size, can you be clearer as to what isn't working?

Comment: It is the size. For a square matrix I use sqrt(2^31). Allocating it outside of main() puts it in the heap rather than on the stack (I think.)

Comment: Actually I have to take that back as I tried to run such a program and it didn't run properly on my Win 10 64-bit. The declaration does get past an error from the compiler so I just assumed it would run. Use the dynamic methods suggested by others.

Comment: a 50000x50000 char array is almost 2.5GB and 10GB for int. In most cases you won't need that much memory for a beginner or intermediate problem. You're probably overthinking and use an algorithm with high complexity (e.g. O(N²) instead of a much more efficient like O(log N)) and your program might never finish in enough time. Or it might be solved with sparse arrays

Comment: This might very well be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282). Show what your real problem is

Answer (score 0):

```
int **array;
int i;

array = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 50000)// <stdlib.h> for malloc

for (i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
   array[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 50000);
```

You can then access the elements as `array[i][j]`.

Comment: [Please consider omitting the cast of `malloc()`'s return value in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Also, that does 50,001 heap allocations which is hardly optimal or very nice. It can be trivially simplified to do 2, and with a tiny bit of work you can just do a single allocation.

Comment: At least it's large enough, by a pretty wide margin: `sizeof int` to be precise. OP asked for a mere `char` array.

Comment: Why are you making arrays of `int` when the question is about `char`?